# How to include the "C" under a line integral while still keeping the limits of integration?

Tags: equations, amsmath

The standard line integral is identical to the normal integral, so often times the "C" is put under it like this:

```
\int_C
```

And for the line integral with limits of integration:

```
\int_{a}^{b}
```

However, I want my students to still know that it is a line integral, so I would like to keep the "C" in addition to the limits of integration. The problem is that I cannot find a way to do so. I have tried experimenting with `\limits` but that does not work either. Here are some of my attempts:

`\int_C \limits_{a}^{b}` (I really thought this one was going to work.)

Is there any way to keep the "C" with the limits? I appreciate all responses :)

Comment: it's not clear what output you want `\int_{Ca}^b` ?  `\mathop{\int_{C}}_{a}^{b}` ?

Comment: If your integral is a line integral, there are no a and b limits. *After* you transform the line integral with a parametrization, you get limits, but it's no longer a line integral. To be picky, it is, but along a different path than the initial one. So I believe you're trying to mislead your students.

Comment: Your question is quite clear to me. However, it is customary to add a label to the integral in a coordinate-free way, naming the path, OR by including the limits for a particular parametrization, but not both. One integral sign is usually enough to remind the reader they’re dealing with a line integral. That has been the case with my students.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\mathop` to generate an operator from an integral with limits. However using

```
\mathop{\int\limits_{C}}\nolimits_{a}^{b}
```

usually will place the `a` to low, because of the depth of the `C`. And if you *smash* the `\int\limits_{c}` the `a` would be place to high. But you can use a `\vphantom{\int}` the once again have the depth of an integral without `C`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathop{\smash[b]{\int\limits_{C}}\vphantom{\int}}\nolimits_{a}^{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @mrwillparker Hope, this is the result you've expected, because from your question it is not absolutely clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I believe you're trying to deceive your students.

A line integral over the curve *C* *can* be computed as an ordinary integral once you know a parameterization of the curve; but in the latter integral there's no remaining explicit trace of the curve *C*.

Anyway, this should do what you want. Note the name I gave to the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\badint}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathrlap{\mathop{\vphantom{\int}}\limits_{\!#1}}}%
  \!%
  \int
}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_C f(z)\,dz = \badint{C}_{a}^{b} f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)\,dt
\]

\[
\int_C f(z)\,dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t)\,dt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On behalf of TSE, I apologize to the OP, a newcomer, for the inappropriate tone of this answer.